# Shown doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, events, system.graphics

```
public void GridCreate()
    {
        Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        SolidBrush brushBlack = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Rectangle[,] block = new Rectangle[16, 16];

        for (int i = 0; i <= block.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n <= block.GetLength(0) - 1; n++)
            {
                block[n, i] = new Rectangle(i * blockSize, n * blockSize, 20, 20);
                g.FillRectangle(brushBlack, block[n, i]);
            }
        }
        data.block = block;
    } 
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridCreate();
        }
```

I'm trying to make a grid in WindowsForms using PictureBox, but related code is not working correctly.This `data.block = block;` part works, but this `g.FillRectangle(brushBlack, block[n, i]);` doesn't work at all. I think the problem is in the `Form1_Shown` event, because this:

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridCreate();
    }
```

executes perfectly fine.

Override `protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)` gives the same result as `Form1_Shown`.

Comment: Try a different event like load, paint, etc.

Comment: What Jeremy said, just be sure to pick the `Paint` event :)

Comment: @Jeremy
Not working :(
Tried load, paint and enter.

Comment: @БорисКот more specifically, paint in the `Paint` event of the picturebox  (not the paint event of the form), and use the `Graphics` object provided in the `PaintEventArgs` of that event.

Comment: In your Shown event call GridCreate(), Refresh() and Invalidate(), in your paint event just call GridCreate()

Comment: I second Even - use the `Paint` event and pass the `e.Graphics` from the event args to the `GridCreate` function. @JAT Calling `Invalidate` on the `Onpaint` will just cause infinite Paint calls and freeze your program.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I edited my comment, sorry @YoryeNathan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `CreateGraphics()`, which is a **temporary** surface that gets erased when the PictureBox refreshes itself.

Just create the grid once, then draw the data in the Paint() event:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        GridCreate();
        pictureBox1.Paint += pictureBox1_Paint;
    }

    private void GridCreate()
    {
        Rectangle[,] block = new Rectangle[16, 16];
        for (int i = 0; i < block.GetLength(1); i++) // this is the 2nd dimension, so GetLength(1)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < block.GetLength(0); n++) // this is the 1st dimension, so GetLength(0)
            {
                block[n, i] = new Rectangle(i * blockSize, n * blockSize, 20, 20);
            }
        }
        data.block = block;
    }

    void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics; // use the SUPPLIED graphics, NOT CreateGraphis()!
        for (int i = 0; i < data.block.GetLength(1); i++) // this is the 2nd dimension, so GetLength(1)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < data.block.GetLength(0); n++) // this is the 1st dimension, so GetLength(0)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, data.block[n, i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And if you want to change `blockSize` and update the display, just call `GridCreate` again and `Invalidate` to force a paint event.